# Which character can be eliminated in svg? Why is an arc rendered into a complete circle?

Tags: svg

The logo of [TV domain](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/domain-names/tv-domain-names/index.xhtml) is svg, I found that its grammar is strange but no error is reported.
`<path d="M19.67 43.46a9.62 9.62 0 110-.05z" fill="#e10e49"></path>`
According to [w3c standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html), I think it should be written like this?
`<path d="M19.67 43.46a9.62 9.62 0 1 1 0-.05z" fill="#e10e49"></path>`
And why is this arc rendered as a complete circle?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 119.19 75.7" height="75.7" width="119.19">
 <path d="M19.67 43.46a9.62 9.62 0 110-.05z" fill="#e10e49"/>
</svg>
```

In Wikimedia Commons it looks like this[image]

Comment: could it be ? `<path d="M19.67 43.46 a9.62 9.62 0 1 10 12" fill="none" stroke="#e10e49"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG 1.1 specification helpfully includes a [BNF](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) for parsing. In there we have

> ```
> elliptical-arc:
>     ( "A" | "a" ) wsp* elliptical-arc-argument-sequence
> elliptical-arc-argument-sequence:
>     elliptical-arc-argument
>     | elliptical-arc-argument comma-wsp? elliptical-arc-argument-sequence
> elliptical-arc-argument:
>     nonnegative-number comma-wsp? nonnegative-number comma-wsp? 
>         number comma-wsp flag comma-wsp? flag comma-wsp? coordinate-pair
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> flag:
>     "0" | "1"
> ```

So as soon as you read the 1 for the flag you're done and you move onto the next item. Whitespace between flags is optional (? means 0 or 1).

The arc is not a complete circle, the z completes it with a straight line but it's small and you don't notice it.

Comment: But the end coordinate is 0,-0.05, Why the result is not the same as Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: I  was stupid, the end point is a relative coordinates, It should not go to the upper left corner.